# How to join all tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, relationship

I am a new programmer and I don't know how to do this.

I have:

- a table named `customers` (cust_id, name)
- a table named `agents` (agent_id, agent_name)
- a table named `authorizations` (cust_id, agent_id)
- a table named `product_services` (p_s_id, cust_id, agent_id, item_name, item_id)

About the `authorizations` table: the `agent_id` is the agent who the is authorised salesperson for `cust_id`.  So, I need to be able to pull only results for this particular `cust_id` under this `agent_id`.

I need to do a query that will return all the products and services that the customer have under all other agents. In the search, it should also return products/services that they have under me as well.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
          product_services.item_name, agents.agent_name,
          customers.name, agents.agent_id, product_services.item_id 
        FROM
          product_services 
        LEFT JOIN agents ON product_services.agent_id = agents.agent_id 
        LEFT JOIN customers ON product_services.cust_id = customers.cust_id 
        WHERE authorizations.agent_id = '$aid'
          AND  product_services.item_name LIKE '%$q%' 
        ORDER BY product_services.id DESC 
        LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

Comment: With db-related questions, it's good form to mention what database you are using.

Comment: From the syntax, it looks like mysql to me

Comment: sorry! i am using phpmyadmin.

Comment: what yes123 means, is that 'phpmyadmin' is an administration interface, and not a database. I guess you're using MySQL then :)

Answer (score 1):

KPO,

Below is a query I used to connect 2 tables.  It would be the same for your query, notice the syntax used starting at "LEFT JOIN"

```
    SELECT 
    user.username,
    groups.group_id, groups.group_name,  
    sign.last_connected, sign.sign_id, sign.sign_name, sign.resolution_x, sign.resolution_y, LEFT(sign.sign_name, 1) AS first_char
FROM
    user
LEFT JOIN(
    groups, sign
)ON(
    user.user_id = groups.userID AND
    groups.group_id = sign.groupID
)
WHERE
    username = ? AND
    UPPER(sign.sign_name) BETWEEN "A" AND "Z"
    OR sign.sign_name BETWEEN "0" AND "9" ORDER BY sign.sign_name
```

Considering your SQL query is initially correct this should work for your LEFT JOIN portion:

```
LEFT JOIN(agents, customers
)ON( product_services.agent_id = agents.agent_id 
AND product_services.cust_id = customers.cust_id)
```

Comment: I still get the same problem.

Comment: the problem is that its showing me results for customers who are not under me.

Comment: How are your customers separated outside of ID?  are they grouped by your name? User name? etc?

Comment: the username is also included in the agent and customer tables.  not sure why i didn't include that in my question

Comment: If your table column is "username" like in my example, and say your username is KPO. Then the WHERE clause would be:

WHERE
     username = 'KPO';

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a query would start with the core table at the root of your criteria... Such as a single customer and join from that...  You also state you want ALL products/services from ALL agents including the "me" agent, you would not want to have a filter on your '$aid' criteria.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN 
      c.cust_id,
      c.name,
      ag.agent_id,
      ag.agent_name,
      ps.item_name,
      ps.p_s_id,
      ps.item_id
   from
      customers c
         join authorizations au
            on c.cust_id = au.cust_id
            [[ AND au.agent_id = '$aid' ]]
            join agents ag
               on au.agent_id = ag.agent_id
            join product_services ps
               on c.cust_id = ps.cust_id
              AND au.agent_id = ps.agent_id
              [[ AND ps.item_name like '%$q%' ]]
   order by
      ps.p_s_id DESC
   limit 
      $start, $limit
```

In the query above, I've put in section where you could apply your

```
[[ AND agent criteria ]]
```

or product/service criteria.  But as you stated, you wanted ALL activity of ALL agents, so I've left it out... Likewise with a possible

```
[[ AND product / service ]]
```

criteria which may/may not be provided and you can very simply strip it out...

-- EDIT PER COMMENT FEEDBACK.

As per your inquiry on how to add more "criteria", its based on the origin of the table.  If its the FIRST table in the "FROM" clause, you'll add a WHERE clause and put criteria to that table... As for the others, like the agents and product services, where I had the [[ criteria ]], you could just expand your entire criteria there (per respective table its joined with).

Such as your [[ product service criteria ]], I could have added something like

```
AND (   (   ps.Item like '%$something'
         OR ps.Item like '%$another'
         OR ps.Item like '%$more' )
     AND ps.OtherField = whatever )
```

Keep your primary "join" conditions which identify the relationship between the tables first and foremost... only THEN do you want to add your restricting criteria... As you can see in my sample above, I've wrapped the entire  AND (     ) clause within parenthesis to see it as a single "unit" condition... such as to the product/service table.

Hope this sample helps you in future querying.

Comment: That did the trick! but how do i add more thinks for the LIKE; e.g OR something.something LIKE '%$q%' OR something.that LIKE '%$q%'

Comment: Thanks Drapp seems like i have created a very complicated query here.  The like function doesn't work properly for some reason.  Its tiem for my night job.  when i am back i will focus on it again.  thanks for your help and lookout for my updates thanks!!

Comment: @DRapp the problem with the search comes from the " AND au.agent_id = ps.agent_id" when i remove that constraint the search works fine but each result shows twice... not sure what do do to fix that..

Comment: Also is it important to use the "au" "c" that you have after table names?

Comment: @KPO... The "au", "c" and "ps" I have after the table names is used as an "Alias" of the table... Like a shortcut... if you are doing long queries and have long table names, you can apply the "alias" for the rest of your query including column names, joins, etc instead of the repeated typing of long names and getting typing errors (oops factor) :)

Comment: ok but i still have to find a way to not get them to repeat??

Comment: @KPO, without seeing the data directly, or cycling through each tier of the join, you might want to try doing "SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN DISTINCT" to prevent duplicates of the columns returned.

Comment: Hey! it still didnt work.  its not duplicate entries its just that its repeating the results..